# Evaluating if statements within switch expression

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested, switch-statement

I've started using UglifyJS, and the way it nested some of the if statements within the switch expression was peculiar. I'm struggling to find any documentation on it. Neither [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) nor [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) say anything explicit about it. The script is running fine, I would just like to know more about how.

Global variable:

```js
var today = new Date();
```

Original script:

```js
function date(date = today) {
  if (date !== today) { date = new Date(date) };
  var year = date.getFullYear().toString(),
    month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(),
    day = date.getDate().toString(),
    shortDay,
    longDay;

  if (month.length === 1) { month = "0" + month };
  if (day.length === 1) { day = "0" + day };
  switch (date.getDay()) {
    case 0: shortDay = 'Sun'; longDay = "Sunday"; break;
    case 1: shortDay = 'Mon'; longDay = "Monday"; break;
    case 2: shortDay = 'Tue'; longDay = "Tuesday"; break;
    case 3: shortDay = 'Wed'; longDay = "Wednesday"; break;
    case 4: shortDay = 'Thu'; longDay = "Thursday"; break;
    case 5: shortDay = 'Fri'; longDay = "Friday"; break;
    case 6: shortDay = 'Sat'; longDay = "Saturday"; break;
  };

  return {
    full: year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + shortDay,
    mmddyyyy: month + '/' + day + '/' + year,
    mmddyy: month + '/' + day + '/' + year.substring(2),
    md: (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '/' + date.getDate().toString(),
    year, month, day, shortDay, longDay
  };
};
```

UglifyJS compressed script (reformatted for readability):

```js
function date(date = today) {
  var shortDay, longDay,
    year = (date = date !== today ? new Date(date) : date).getFullYear().toString(),
    month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(),
    day = date.getDate().toString();

  switch (1 === month.length && (month = "0" + month), 1 === day.length && (day = "0" + day), date.getDay()) {
    case 0: shortDay = "Sun", longDay = "Sunday"; break;
    case 1: shortDay = "Mon", longDay = "Monday"; break;
    case 2: shortDay = "Tue", longDay = "Tuesday"; break;
    case 3: shortDay = "Wed", longDay = "Wednesday"; break;
    case 4: shortDay = "Thu", longDay = "Thursday"; break;
    case 5: shortDay = "Fri", longDay = "Friday"; break;
    case 6: shortDay = "Sat", longDay = "Saturday"
  }
  
  return {
    full: year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + shortDay,
    mmddyyyy: month + "/" + day + "/" + year,
    mmddyy: month + "/" + day + "/" + year.substring(2),
    md: (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "/" + date.getDate().toString(),
    year: year, month: month, day: day,
    shortDay: shortDay, longDay: longDay
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is the part that is the most peculiar:

```
switch (1 === month.length && (month = "0" + month), 1 === day.length && (day = "0" + day), date.getDay()) {
    case 0: shortDay = "Sun", longDay = "Sunday"; break;
    case 1: shortDay = "Mon", longDay = "Monday"; break;
    case 2: shortDay = "Tue", longDay = "Tuesday"; break;
    case 3: shortDay = "Wed", longDay = "Wednesday"; break;
    case 4: shortDay = "Thu", longDay = "Thursday"; break;
    case 5: shortDay = "Fri", longDay = "Friday"; break;
    case 6: shortDay = "Sat", longDay = "Saturday"
  }
```

### Comma operator

First of all, there is a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in JavaScript which always returns the last element.
For example:

```
const x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
console.log(x) // 5
```

So this:

```
switch (1 === month.length && (month = "0" + month), 1 === day.length && (day = "0" + day), date.getDay()) {
```

Looks exactly like this:

```
switch (date.getDay()) {
```

From the `switch`'s point of view.

### && operator

Also, [`&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) stops if the left operand is falsy:

```
false && console.log('something') // doesn't log anything
true && console.log('something') // logs something
```

So:

```
// month is equal to '0' + month, but only if 1 === month.length
1 === month.length && (month = "0" + month)
// same here
1 === day.length && (day = "0" + day)
```